# iOS app crash at the lauch

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, xcode5

My app is crashing as soon as i launch it. Don't know what the problem is. It was working fine before. All of sudden it stopped working. Can someone please help to fix the crash issue. here is the Log:

2014-09-09 12:47:56.029ePractice[3701:60b]exception (

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x01d8a1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018558e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   UIKit                               0x00a79400 -[UIStoryboard name] + 0
3   UIKit                               0x00515692 -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 53
4   UIKit                               0x00515949 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 245
5   UIKit                               0x0051454e -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 543
6   UIKit                               0x00528f92 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3517
7   UIKit                               0x00529555 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
8   UIKit                               0x00516250 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 683
9   GraphicsServices                    0x040d1f02 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
10  GraphicsServices                    0x040d1a0d PurpleEventCallback + 46
11  CoreFoundation                      0x01d05ca5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
12  CoreFoundation                      0x01d059db __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
13  CoreFoundation                      0x01d3068c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
14  CoreFoundation                      0x01d2f9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
15  CoreFoundation                      0x01d2f7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
16  UIKit                               0x00513d9c -[UIApplication _run] + 840
17  UIKit                               0x00515f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
18  ePractice                           0x00176b94 main + 164
19  libdyld.dylib                       0x0263970d start + 1
20  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
```

)

Comment: There should be a bit more to the stacktrace - particularly an error message, or at least the class of exception that's being thrown.

Comment: What's the complete error message?

Comment: I have edited the log. Now i have put the entire log.

Comment: You're still missing the exception message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have specified a correct Storyboard filename here:

```
Click on ProjectName-> General Tab -> Deployment Info -> Main Interface.
```

Probably you have renamed your file and forget to change it here.

Comment: Just deleted Storyboard file and added again. Solved my problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Check whether you have correct storyboard name in `Info.plist` file.

Also, check if your storyboard is there in `Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources`

Comment: Thanks bhargavg. Everything looks fine. But still its crashing. :(